# webdriver - selecting country from drop down list without using xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<a id="SIU2_country" class="button combobox-button country" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true; if (event.stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); }" tabindex="9" style="cursor: auto;">
<span id="SIU2_country_span">&nbsp;</span>
<div class="combobox-menu" style="width: 298px; max-height: 212px; display: block;">
<div class="combobox-menu-item">
<span>United States</span>
</div>
<div class="combobox-menu-item">
<span>United Kingdom</span>
</div>
<div class="combobox-menu-item">
```

Trying to avoid using xpath in webdriver:

```
(By.xpath("//a[@id='SIU2_country']/div/div/span[contains(text(),'United Kingdom')]"));
```

How do I select United Kingdom from drop down list using id or cssselector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
List<WebElement> menuItemsList = driver.findElement(By.id("SIU2_country")).findElements(By.className("combobox-menu-item"));
WebElement menuItem = menuItemsList.get(1).findElement(By.tagName("span"));
```

It's kind of ugly though... May I ask what's wrong with using xpath here?

Comment: Thanks. Will stick to xpath for this element. I try to avoid using xpath in webdriver as much as I can.